# Comparing date and time

Tags: vb.net

I want to compare date and time.
I tried date1.Date.CompareTo(date2.Date) but I donot know how to add time to it.
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to compare time, you need to declare it as `DateTime` instead of `Date`

```
Dim dt1 As DateTime
Dim dt2 As DateTime
dt1 = Now
dt2 = Now.AddMilliseconds(5)
Dim dt3 As DateTime
MessageBox.Show(dt2.Compare(dt2, dt1).ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Check DateDiff if you want the difference between these two dates in either days, hours, minutes, etc.

OR use d.AddDays, d.AddHours, etc. where d is a variable of type date

Answer (score -1):

```
    Dim dt1 As Date = Now
    'Dim dt2 As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, 1, dt1)   'Add 1 year
    'Dim dt2 As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, dt1)  'Add 1 month
    Dim dt2 As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, dt1)     'Add 1 day
    'Dim dt2 As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 1, dt1)   'Add 1 hour
    'Dim dt2 As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, 1, dt1) 'Add 1 minute
    'Dim dt2 As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, 1, dt1) 'Add 1 second
    If Format(dt1, "yyyyMMdd") < Format(dt2, "yyyyMMdd") Then
        MsgBox("dt1 is lower then dt2")
    ElseIf Format(dt1, "yyyyMMdd") > Format(dt2, "yyyyMMdd") Then
        MsgBox("dt1 is greater then dt2")
    ElseIf Format(dt1, "yyyyMMdd") = Format(dt2, "yyyyMMdd") Then
        MsgBox("dt1 is equal dt2")
    End If
```